# updateData() vs insertData() in Google Fit

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk, google-fit-api

I'm building an Android app which syncs data to Google Fit and uses the Google Fit SDK to achieve that - but I'm pretty sure my question also applies when you are using the REST API.

Within my app users can also change data inserted to Google Fit. The Google Fit SDK has two distinct functions to handle those kind of things: `insertData()` and `updateData()`.

Now, I don't want to keep track of whether a user changed an already synced data point vs whether it is an entirely new datapoint. I just want to have a simple Boolean flag which indicates whether a data point has already been uploaded to Google Fit or not - that's to keep things simple and reliable on the app's side.

So when a user creates a new data point in my app, I set a `syncedToGoogleFit` flag for that data point in my DB to `0`. When the data point has been synced to Google Fit I set it to `1`. When the user later changes the data point in my app I set it to `0` again and so on.

However, the Google Fit SDK distinguishes between inserting and updating which means a simple Boolean wouldn't be enough to track changes on my end as `insertData()` will fail if there already is a data point for a given timestamp. Is it possible to always call `updateData()` even if I am actually inserting new data and that way get by with just the Boolean flag on my end?

Looking at the documentation it should be okay, but I would feel safer if someone could confirm that. Also I'd like to know whether there are any potential performance implications of the approach outlined above, but I guess this is just something the SDK devs can answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've played around quite a bit with the SDK now and from what I am seeing I can say, that using `updateData()` seems to work just fine.